# How, if at all, does Midi-chlorian count relate to blood volume?

Tags: star-wars, science, the-force

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When Jedi lose parts of their body, does their midi-chlorian count and strength in the Force diminish?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4097/when-jedi-lose-parts-of-their-body-does-their-midi-chlorian-count-and-strength)

This question is based on [Is the relation between midi-chlorian count and Force ability a correlation or a causation? If the latter, in which direction?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21960/is-the-relation-between-midi-chlorian-count-and-force-ability-a-correlation-or-a)  However the accepted answer ends in a note:

> ..you could not tack on Force sensitivity to someone by artificially augmenting his midi-chlorian count, it imply there's is some kind of affinity between the host and the midi-chlorian.

Suggesting that somehow the 'inner being' was responsible for the count.

So in the final analysis, if a Jedi loses a limb, does the subsequent blood volume loss mean any difference in their ability to draw upon/exercise the force, or not?

Comment: phantom42 beat me to it.  Probable duplicate.  Good question, though.